# Signup and login inputs in a single form

Tags: php, authentication, registration

How to code form element and/or (php) script for this type of form? Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden text box(or checkbox...) as state holder. When sign-up button clicked this textbox text set to, well, 'signup'(using javascript click handler attached to that sign-up button). Then form submitted. On server-side you can check for this parameter in request. Hope this help.

UPDATE:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="get">
    <p>
    Login: <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    Password: <INPUT type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Signup"> <input name="action" type="submit" value="Login">
    </p>
 </form>
```

Is this your form?

Not that when you click Signup action=Signup but when you click Login action=Login

UPDATE 1:

```
if($_GET('action') == 'Signup'){
   //redirect to full signup form
   header( 'Location: signup.php' ); //note: html tags NOT ALLOWED before this line.
else{
   //process logon (calculate hash and so on)
}
```

Why do you need separate signup.php? Well, user MUST type his/her password twice. Then you need confirmation e-mail and so on.

You see, this stuff can be implemented in thousand different ways. If you want more useful help you should give me more information. E.g:

1) Do you use MVC?
2) Do you use templates? and so on.

By the way I used GET for clarity(you can see form field values in address bar). In real project you should use POST in form and  hence $_POST in login.php

Comment: on server-side(PHP): if ($_GET['signup'] == 'signup'){}

on client-side(jQuery) $('signup_button').click(function(){ $('signup').attr('value','signup');}

Comment: You see, Mike. The problem is that you did not told how this form should look. Which fields it  contains ? For my form see  update.

Comment: ok it was typo - you should read as "Note that when you click..."

Comment: Why did you mention "Why do you need separate signup.php?"? Why "user MUST type his/her password twice"?

Comment: ok it can be the same login.php it actually doesn't matter. 

user must retype his password when he creates new account isn't it?

Comment: So after all we need both signup.php and login.php?

Comment: Sorry? I think action="/login.php" enables only login but not signup. Otherwise it is somewhat wrong to name the handling php script as "login". In addition the php script (handler?) you gave does not work.